# Is it difficult to manage iInheriting a client dataset from another?

Tags: delphi

Say I have a client dataset CDSPerson that acts as a wrapper around a Persons database table.  Say I have another table, PersonBenefits, that joins 1:1 back to the Persons table.

Say I wrap a Delphi class around CDSPerson, PersonClass, and another class around CDSPersonBenefits, PersonBenefitsClass, to read and write records.  PersonBenefitsClass inherits from PersonClass so it can provide data from both tables.  I'd like to be able to  write data back to either table through PersonBenefitsClass.

Has anyone developed a clean way to handle the SQL query, provider flags and commit logic in the inherited class so that (a) fields stay aligned with the parent class and (b) both database tables can be updated?

Is there a reference for this that I can't find?  Is this just a bad idea?  I'm using Delphi 2007.

Comment: Say you edit your post to remove all of the "Say I" and try posting something that looks like what you're actually trying to do, so say people can maybe make some sense of what you're actually trying to ask? Like, really dude, post something that is not so much noise and has some substance, and maybe someone can help you with the problem you're like trying to, say, solve. Say, like with an answer?

Comment: Are you trying to make an n-tier application? Why the need to use additional classes if you have all the functionality you need within the `TClientDataSet` component? Explain a bit more why you are trying to do what you described and we may give you a viable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to develop a business-object-to-database mapping framework, (commonly known as ORM, Object-Relational Mapper,) you're going to need to put in a bit of architecture to make relationships like this work properly.  Here's one way to do it:

PersonClass and BenefitsClass both inherit from BusinessObjectClass.  BusinessObjectClass is a base class that contains the general logic to interact with the dataset.  It has a list object of some sort that contains a list of relation objects.

Each relation object is a special object that contains either one or a list of BusinessObjectClass descendants, plus extra data describing the foreign-key relationship between the two tables.  When BusinessObjectClass does its queries and its updates, it needs to iterate through all its relation objects and have them do their own queries and updates as appropriate.

In your composite object, (PersonWithBenefitsClass,) in the constructor, call **inherited** and then set up a relation object that describes the related BenefitsClass.  Make sure that any inserts of new objects are done in the right order to preserve referential integrity.

That's the basic idea.  (One basic idea. There are probably plenty of other ways to do it.)  I'll leave the details of exactly how you implement it up to you.